# Which groups of people were awake at night in antiquity?

Tags: ancient-history, classical-antiquity

I've come across claims that prehistoric people didn't get much sleep, which seems to be extrapolated from observations of existing primitive cultures. I'm wondering whether there's something more solid for a somewhat more recent time, say during 0-500 CE. This probably varies by region, maybe mostly depending on level of development. A few groups of people that I could come up with that were almost certainly up at night would be

- night guards
- sailors
- astronomers
- possibly traveling merchants
- people partying in taverns

I'm curious what groups are known to have been active during the night, and I'm not picky with regard to region or which part of antiquity really; anything that's reasonably well known will be interesting.

Question: which groups of people are known to have been active at night in antiquity?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/6171/how-many-hours-per-day-did-a-sumerian-farmer-sleep) useful and also [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34348/did-people-practice-multiphasic-sleep-in-the-middle-ages).

Comment: @LarsBosteen They're somewhat related, and do help, thanks!

Comment: You would certainly have the [Vigiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigiles) in Imperial Rome, as just one example.

Comment: Parents of newborns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from the [Vigiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigiles) (basically, firemen and police) mentioned by *sempaiscuba* in his comment, there were quite a few groups of people who would have been active at night in Imperial Rome.

Perhaps most numerous were **household slaves**. They could be required to perform a wide range of duties at night as most were expected to be available at all times:

- running errands (e.g. carrying messages)
- if the master went out, slaves would be required to light the way with torches or provide protection
- serving at banquets and generally being on hand to fetch things, fan the guests or assist those who had drunk too much

[image]

*Pompeii: "painting of banqueting scene from west wall of triclinium. End of the Banquet. The guests are rising but one of them cannot stand up without assistance[3](http://www.pompeiiinpictures.com/pompeiiinpictures/R5/5%2002%2004%20p4.htm)." Source: [Pompeii in Pictures](http://www.pompeiiinpictures.com/pompeiiinpictures/R5/5%2002%2004%20p4.htm)*

- bedroom slaves were in or near the master / mistress’ bedroom at night (even when couples were making out) in case he/she needed anything

[image]

*"Fresco of couple in bed. Man talks to his shy bride. A servant on the left watches the scene." Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Casa_della_Farnesina_-_Cubiculum_D_-_Right_wall_-_Left_Side.jpg).*

- watchmen and doormen
- nurses for infants
- Weaving and yarning were done by the female slaves of less wealthy Romans who often had their servants multi-task.

Among other groups active at night were:

- Temple attendants
- Workers in taverns and brothels
- Street vendors
- Soldiers acting as sentries for armies camped for the night
- Bakers had to get up early to prepare bread
- Wagon drivers delivering goods
- Fishermen
- Entertainers, especially musicians
- Christians sometimes [met at night](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=O7-JANm7mZkC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=christians%20meeting%20at%20night%20ancient%20rome&source=bl&ots=ps1kkjSC7C&sig=TDgn8-RG9GOVwT3WczYh7tL5x2w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2jKHw6tvfAhVH7mEKHWTXDqgQ6AEwEXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=night&f=false)
- Some authors would write at night; this was known as [lucubratio](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/429195?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). This could have been simply
  working late, or waking up and working and then going back to bed.
  This could also vary with the seasons, as was the case with both
  Pliny the Elder and Pliny the Younger
- According to [S. Sticka](https://bir.brandeis.edu/bitstream/handle/10192/33877/StickaThesis2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), "Juvenal relates the importance of fathers training their sons to wake in the middle of the night in order to accomplish their tasks."
- Some slaves also turned to crime at night (as suggested by *@bof* in
  his comment).

As Jason Linn points out in his doctoral thesis, *[The Dark Side of Rome](https://www.alexandria.ucsb.edu/lib/ark:/48907/f3w66hxh)* (2014) many of these jobs were boring

> Not only did many night jobs entail periods of waiting, but often
>   waiting alone: guards waited for trouble; nurses waited on sleeping
>   children; prostitutes waited for customers.... With plenty of free
>   time many night workers had to stay awake and endure boredom alone...
>   Some guards were even chained to their posts.

---

Other sources:

Shaun Sticka *[Segmented Sleep in First-Century Roman Society](https://bir.brandeis.edu/bitstream/handle/10192/33877/StickaThesis2017.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)* (Master's thesis, 2017)

K. D. Matthews, *[The Embattled Driver in Ancient Rome](https://www.penn.museum/sites/expedition/the-embattled-driver-in-ancient-rome/)*

A. R. Ekirch, *[At Day's Close](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/At_Day_s_Close.html?id=mIaB7l0TYoAC&redir_esc=y)*

Comment: Thieves and burglars?

Comment: Most of those groups I hadn't thought about, thanks! I'm gonna take a look at the sources, and leave the question open for a few more days in case someone else has more info to add.

Comment: @G.Bach I'll be adding to this answer, and also I'll add links to make it easier to find the sources.

Comment: The "wagon drivers" bullet point shouldn't be underestimated.  Rome had a population (at times) of up to a million people.  For significant periods, the use of wagons on city streets during the day time was banned.  This means that ALL transportation activities requiring the use of a vehicle would happen at night.

Comment: I've been a guard long time ago. I **hated** night shifts. The boredom is very real. Even worse; you don't want it to get 'interesting'...

Comment: @tbrookside thats really interesting, do you know how long that situation persisted? by the time the industrial revolution came around changes probably had to be made, but id be surprised if they kept it up that long

Comment: @G.Bach Rome's population peaked an estimated 1 million during the 2nd century and was down to around 30,000 during the 6th century. This decline would have made it no longer necessary to ban wagons during the day. Best guess is the ban would probably have been lifted for good during the 4th century.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I gotta find out why it dropped to 3% of its population, where did all the people go o_0

Comment: @G.Bach It has been postulated the [birth rate was exceeded by the death rate](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/36075/dynamics-of-urban-populations-in-pre-modern-times/49757#49757) and that, consequently, Rome relied heavily on immigrants to maintain and increase its population. When the centre of the empire shifted east, Rome became less wealthy and less attractive to immigrants. The city was also sacked three times (410, 455, 546 AD). Have look at the pdf [Death and disease in the ancient city of Rome](https://www.princeton.edu/~pswpc/pdfs/scheidel/040901.pdf) for more info.